# Why accessing a templated variant as return value throwing exception

Tags: c++

Why is a templated variant return type cause bad_variant_access exception?

```
Unhandled exception at 0x779508B2 in Project2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_variant_access at memory location 0x00B3FB00.
```

When in another program, which is bigger, the statement in main got executed without error, but prints out some strange value other than `142`. which seemingly is an Undefined behavior.

```cpp
/////////////////////minified_main.cpp/////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>


template <typename T>
class THolder {
public:
    THolder() = default;
    THolder(T p) : t_(p) {}
    THolder(const THolder<T>& other) = default;

public:
    T t_;
};

class THolderProducer {
public:
    THolderProducer() = default;
    std::variant<THolder<int>, char*>&& operator()() { return std::move(std::variant<THolder<int>, char*>(THolder<int>{142})); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout <<'[' << std::get<0>(THolderProducer()()).t_ << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The compiler [can warn about this](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yvrf_C).

Comment: Your `operator()` returns reference to a temporary.

Comment: changed to 
```cpp
std::variant<THolder<int>, char*>&& operator()() { return std::move(std::variant<THolder<int>, char*>(THolder<int>{142})); }
```
Did compile, but printed value is 0, like undefined behavior,

Comment: The point is that you can't return a reference to anything local. Just return `std::variant<THolder<int>, char*>` instead of a ref.

Comment: @churill but I did explicitly `std::move`d.

Comment: a template rarely is the cause for an exception being thrown ;) there are no templates at run-time

Comment: Is there something called "Ask Herb Sutter Anything" out there :D ?

Comment: @Michaelzh I think `std::move` does not do, what you think it does.

Comment: Another instance of the Rvalue Reference Overload Syndrome. Just get rid of all the unneeded rvalue references and random `std::move`s that don't really accomplish anything except create a bunch of temporaries and undefined behavior.

Comment: I seems like you don't really understand move-semantics, rvalue references or `std::move`. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-is-move-semantics

Comment: I only properly understood move-semantics after reading this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @Kerndog73You didn't understand, the question is How come is the undefined behavior, not the Cliché "What is move semantic"

Comment: @Michaelzh:  it's undefined behavior because you're returning a reference (to a temp) and attempting to use it after the target (the temp) has been destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program basically boils down to this:

```
int &&f() {
  return 5;
} 

int main() {
  return f();
}
```

This is undefined behaviour because you're returning a reference to a temporary. If I compile this with optimizations disabled, the exit code is `5`. If I compile with optimizations, the exit code is `176`. To me, that is irrefutable proof that the program contains undefined behaviour (or there's a bug in the compiler but in this case I doubt it).

`main` is accessing a reference to an object whose lifetime has ended. It is undefined what happens when you do that so returning `176` when you expected `5` is perfectly reasonable.

---

This program can be simplified down further to make it more obvious that this is undefined behaviour.

```
int *f() {
  int five = 5;
  return &five;
}

int main() {
  return *f();
}
```

`f` returns a pointer to an integer allocated on the stack frame of `f`. When `f` returns, the stack frame of `f` is popped from the call stack so `five` is outside of the call stack. `main` dereferences a pointer to an object outside of the stack.

---

While not quite the same, this is pretty similar to accessing elements outside of an array:

```
int main() {
  int array[1] = {};
  return array[5];
}
```

In the case of the function that returns a pointer, you're accessing an object that existed at one point but no longer does. In the case of the array, you're accessing an object that never existed in the first place.